# Functions defined after protocol extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, oop, protocols

When I was watching 2 WWDC 2015 lectures, they mentioned the following code:

```
func == (lhs: Polygon, rhs: Polygon) -> Bool {
  return lhs.corners == rhs.corners
}
extension Polygon : Equatable {}
func == (lhs: Circle, rhs: Circle) -> Bool {
  return lhs.center == rhs.center
    && lhs.radius == rhs.radius
}
extension Circle : Equatable {}
```

Shouldn't the equatable function declarations go inside the extensions? Right now, they're outside and existing where? In other words, shouldn't it look like this?

```
extension Polygon : Equatable {
    func == (lhs: Polygon, rhs: Polygon) -> Bool {
      return lhs.corners == rhs.corners
    }
}

extension Circle : Equatable {
    func == (lhs: Circle, rhs: Circle) -> Bool {
       return lhs.center == rhs.center
       && lhs.radius == rhs.radius
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues when you are trying the second version:

1. Operators are only allow at global scope
2. The extension doesn't qualify to Equatable because of 1.

In other words, No you can't do it based on the scope of the operator declaration.

Comment: Aha! So in reason 2, because it would be nested inside the extension, Swift wouldn't see it, and therefore would throw an error that Circle or Polygon does not conform to equatable?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Operator functions are always in the global space, not inside the class or extension.

Comment: Got it - I've never defined an operator function before, so I wasn't sure. Thanks!